# SQL4499N when connecting to DB2 express V10.5 from IBM Data Studio 4.1

Tags: database, installation, db2, windows-10-desktop, ibm-data-studio

Background: I have to transfer VS 2003 and VB6 applications from Windows 7 to a new Windows 10 Home machine. The applications are currently using DB2 9.7, Sql Server or Ms Access via ODBC. I decided to consolidate all dbs to DB2 on the W10 machine, using separate schemas for the different databases. The W10 machine is normally standalone (No Lan or Internet).

Details: I installed DB2 Express V10.5 and IBM Data Studio 4.1 on the W10 machine. DB2 Express gives me enough for my db needs, and I assume that Data Studio will give me similar GUI functionality as DB2 Control Center v9 on the W7 machine.
I installed DB2 and Data Studio under at least two different user ids(one being Db2admin), all with windows admin rights, and different credentials.
But every time I try to login/connect in Data Studio I'm rejected with SQ4499N, I must be doing something fundamentally Wrong.

---

when running the following commands from CMD I get the shown results.

db2val

DBI1379I  The db2val command is running. This can take several minutes.

DBI1333I  Installation file validation for the DB2 copy DB2COPY1
was successful.

DBI1339I  The instance validation for the instance DB2 was
successful.

### DBI1343I  The db2val command completed successfully. For details, see
the log file C:\Users\User\DOCUME~1\DB2LOG\db2val-Wed Mar 02 16_28_37 2022.log.

DB2LEVEL returns:
DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable: "DB2")
uses "32" bits and DB2 code release "SQL10054" with level identifier
"0605010E".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v10.5.400.191", "s140813", "IP23617", and Fix
Pack "4".
Product is installed at "C:\PROGRA~2\IBM\SQLLIB" with DB2 Copy Name "DB2COPY1".

### DB2Start returns:
SQL1026N  The database manager is already active.

Switching to DB2 CLP
db2 => List Active Databases returns:
SQL1611W  No data was returned by Database System Monitor.

db2 => List database directory returns:
SQL1057W  The system database directory is empty.  SQLSTATE=01606

db2 => list system odbc data sources returns:
DB21037W  No data sources found.

Checking Google and stackoverflow didn't yield any suitable help, at least I didn't see it.
My experience is as app developer, not db2 admin except what is needed for app dev, and I had no problems with DB2 V9.7 on W7, but I'm lost what to do.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This question is not about programming.  Db2 is telling you that there are no databases in your instance.  Did you create any databases, or did you restore and databases from Db2-backups taken on the db2v9.7 environment?

Comment: There is no such an sql message: SQL4499N. There is very generic jdbc error code. [Error codes issued by the IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=jsri-error-codes-issued-by-data-server-driver-jdbc-sqlj). Edit your question with the result of the following commands on the server from Start->Run->db2cwadmin: `db2set DB2COMM`, `db2 list db directory`, `db2 get dbm cfg | findstr /I "svce"`. Check if the Db2 instance port (from the last command) is available from your client.

Comment: There should be at least the Sample database from the installation. And of course there are no other databases, thats why I need to connect to Data Studio to create one, which gives me SQL4499N. The commands issued were to verify the installation.

Comment: Sorry, I read your question not carefully. Empty output of `list db directory` means that there is no databases cataloged at least at the instance. So, you need to create some database to connect to it from DS first.

Comment: Mao, If I would have restored data bases from DB2V9.7 I would have said so.

Comment: Mark, thats what I'm trying to do in Data Studio but can't connect, maybe I haven't mentioned that client machine and DB2 server is on the same machine. I didn't mention it because it didnt make any difference on W7 DB2V9.7

Comment: Sometimes the comments disappear, I'm new to StackOverflow, so sorry about that.

Comment: Mark, SQL4499N is apparently the cuter form of -4499  @ https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/search/4499

Comment: Again SQL4499N is not a cutter of JDBC driver error code, but the numeric part of SQL message doesn't really intersect with JDBC driver error codes. There is no such an SQL message SQL4499N in the [sql4000-sql4999](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=messages-sql4000-sql4999) range. Try to create the database manually from db2cwadmin and register it in DS by host + port number afterwards.

Comment: Will try, but have to wait till tomorrow, as the machine is in use. But what is db2cwadmin, and how do I register it(host is localhost, port is 50000)

Comment: `Start->Run->db2cwadmin`, and `db2 create db mydb` there. Use `New Connection to a Database` (top left corner) button in the `Administration Database` perspective.

Comment: Good morning Mark,

Comment: Good morning Mark, I ran your commands, the command 'db2 create db mydb' created successfully a database, I could connect to it in Data Studio, so I would say that solved my problem, thank you. How do I close this problem and award points to you?

Answer (score 0):

The prerequisites and expected behavior is described at the [Configuring the IBM Data Studio client for remote operations](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/data-studio/4.1.1?topic=tasks-configuring-data-studio-client-remote-operations) link.
You got this error either because of misconfiguration or some DS bug / unexpected behavior.
The solution was to create the database manually and just to register this database in DS afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

In practical terms: DB2 V10.5 SQL-Express failed to install the Sample Database. IBM Data Studio tried to connect to the Sample Database and failed the operation with SQL4499N. Manually creating a database overcame this problem.